# Jupyter syntax highlight in <code> environment

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I was wondering if it was possible to highlight code written using the HTML `<code>...</code>` tags in a similar fashion to the native markdown code block using the tripe backtick ```` ``` ````.

I prefer the `<code>...</code>` environment due to its ability to be customized using css, as I want code to stand out visually.

Comment: `<code>` is for [inline code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code), but you seem to think about code blocks - in that case I would use `<pre>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the styles of the code syntax-highlighted by triple backtick by wrapping it in a `<div>`:

````
<div style="font-weight: bold">
    
```javascript
var x = 1;
function y() {
    return 0;
}
```
    
</div>
````

Note the extra new lines (otherwise it will not render properly). This works well in JupyterLab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**JupyterLab jupytext**
This extension adds a few Jupytext commands to the command palette. You can use it to select the desired ipynb/text pairing for your notebook.

[image]

Comment: I think you meant to post this answer to a different question ;)